# Adding zeroes to date for numbers less than 10

Tags: python

I am trying to add zeroes to a date if the day/month is less than 10.

For example, if 2/12/200 is entered, convert it to 02/12/2000.

```
userDate = input("What is the date? Please enter in MM/DD/YYYY format")

newDate = ''
newDate = userDate[3:5]+ "."+userDate[0:2]+"."+ userDate[6:]
print (newDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split the `userDate` on `/` rather slice it, e.g.:

```
m, d, y = userDate.split('/')
```

It pretty easy to left fill, and it is covered in the linked duplicate, here's one way:

```
m = m.zfill(2)       # 02
d = d.zfill(2)       # 12
```

Padding to the right is slightly different:

```
y = y.ljust(4, '0')  # 2000
```

You can then `join()` them back up:

```
newDate = '/'.join([d, m, y])
```

You can do this all in one line using `str.format()` and the formatting mini language, e.g.:

```
newDate = '{:>02s}/{:>02s}/{:<04s}'.format(*userDate.split('/'))  # 02/12/2000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_date = "/".join([i.zfill(2) for idx, i in enumerate(userDate.split("/"))])
```

Comment: The year isn't padded to 4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> userDate = str(input("What is the date? Please enter in MM/DD/YYYY format"))
What is the date? Please enter in MM/DD/YYYY format'2/12/200'
>>> m,d,y = userDate.split('/')
>>> m = m.zfill(2)           # For Left padding
>>> d = d.zfill(2)           # For Left padding
>>> y = y.ljust(4, '0')      # For Right padding
>>> print """%s/%s/%s""" % (m,d,y)
02/12/2000
>>>
```